# Receiver thread for receiving ip/tcp packets but also responding in it not quite working

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, ip

[image: Wireshark view of these packets]

This is my almost full code which I think sending valid IP header for a TCP packet. But my code fails the Wireshark test that it's not recognized as TCP packet; instead Wireshark just label it as hideous raw packet with out any source and destination IPs. This is really a simple IPs packet that I was sure that does the job of having passed Wireshark test no it doesn't.

What am I doing wrong?  currently no clue to look further on this how to debug it, what else I can set in my tcp or ip header. before it was giving me message in Wireshark Fragmented TCP packet what that even means, then started saying its simply malformed packet now its giving me messages that  these response packets responding is simply raw packets sending from my this code with out source or destination ips, considering for TCP is not even showing that pane

```
void * receiver(void *data)
{

    
    int recvlen = -1;
    int writelen = -1;
    

    while (!_do_exit) {
        char buf[VPN_MAX_MTU] = {0};
        char buf_1[VPN_MAX_MTU] = {0};
        memset(buf,0,VPN_MAX_MTU);
        memset(buf_1,0,VPN_MAX_MTU);
        char *str_source=malloc(18);
        char *str_dest=malloc(18);
        memset(str_source,0,18);
        memset(str_dest,0,18);
       
        recvlen=read(_tun_fd,buf,VPN_MAX_MTU);
       debug("SR:%04d\n", recvlen);
       struct iphdr *iph=(struct iphdr *)buf;   
       struct iphdr *ip=(struct iphdr *)buf_1;
       char str_src[18]={0};
       char str_dest_t[18]={0};
       memcpy(&ip->saddr,&iph->daddr,sizeof(uint32_t));
       memcpy(&ip->daddr,&iph->saddr,sizeof(uint32_t));
       printf("IN %s %s\n",get_ip_str_1(iph->saddr,str_src),get_ip_str_1(iph->daddr,str_dest_t));
       //clear the str_str and str_dest_t with memset(,0)
       printf("OUT %s %s\n",get_ip_str_1(ip->saddr,str_src),get_ip_str_1(ip->daddr,str_dest_t));
        
    ip->ihl         = 5;
    ip->version     = 4;
    ip->tot_len     = sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct tcphdr);
    ip->protocol    = IPPROTO_TCP;
    ip->check = in_cksum((unsigned short *)ip, sizeof(struct iphdr)); 
    
       uint16_t k=csum(ip,sizeof(*ip));
       ip->check=k;
       printf("checksum %d | %d\n",iph->check,ip->check);
       int i=iph->ihl*4;
       struct tcphdr *tcph=(struct tcphdr *)(buf+i);
       int j=(struct iphdr *)(ip->ihl*4);
       struct tcphdr *tcp=(struct tcphdr *)(buf_1+j);
       populate_tcp_some(tcph,tcp);
       printf("received syn = %d\n",tcph->syn); 
       if(tcph->syn==1)
       {
               populate_tcp_some(tcph,tcp);
           tcp->syn=1;
           tcp->ack=1;
           tcp->dest=tcph->source;
           tcp->source=htons(80);
           printf("received tcp syn = %d\n",tcph->syn);
       }
       else{
               populate_tcp_some(tcph,tcp);
           tcp->syn=0;
           tcp->ack=1;
           tcp->dest=tcph->source;
           tcp->source=htons(80);
     
           printf("sending tcp syn = %d ack = %d\n",tcp->syn,tcp->ack);
       
       }
       tcp->check=0;
       tcp->check=tcp_chksum(ip,tcp);
       printf("checksums %d | %d\n",tcph->check,tcp->check);
       
        if (recvlen > 0) {

            writelen = write(_tun_fd, buf_1, sizeof(*ip));
            debug("TW:%04d\n", writelen);
            if (writelen < 0) {
                debug("%s: rwrite() %s [%d]\n", _progname, strerror(errno), errno);
            }
        } else if (recvlen < 0) {
            debug("%s: rrecvfrom() %s\n", _progname, strerror(errno));
 
        } else if (recvlen == 0) {
 
        }
    }

    debug("** Receiver ending.\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Is the constant IPPROTO_TCP in host or network byte order? does wireshark see the same constant you are supposed to put in?

Comment: @Effie this answer does it without htons https://stackoverflow.com/a/13620771/4808760

Comment: @Effie should I use htons https://stackoverflow.com/a/13620771/4808760

Comment: you should check what value does wireshark see first.

Comment: or at least show us what the wireshark sees. it is kinda hard to debug without the error message.

Comment: @Effie wireshark not setting protocol for these packets simply tag them as raw packet. Raw packets doent have or dont show this field in wireshark I think

Comment: WHAT is the value of protocol field in wireshark and what is the value of IPPROTO_TCP constant. Are they the same? Are they the same except network byte order? Are they different in any other way? It cannot not show it. If wireshark saw an IP packet, it has a value for the field.

Comment: @Effie I have added wireshark image with question

Comment: are you capturing the whole data? because it captured 16 bytes, while you should have min 40 bytes of IP and TCP header.

Comment: @Effie how to do this `you should have min 40 bytes of IP and TCP header.` my client tcp packets are showing correctly why would server packets show 16 bytes for my code program and use 40 byte display for client connect packets

Comment: why `writelen = write(_tun_fd, buf_1, **sizeof(*ip)**);` instead of total length?

Comment: this is kinda the question :)

Comment: now I am writing 100 bytes still raw packets shown

Comment: now we need to figure out why  first 6 bytes are zeroes

Comment: @Effie u mean my write function call buffer 6 bytes showing 0 on wireshark.

Comment: yes, because i am pretty sure wireshark cannot parse them because they are zeroes and they should not be.

Comment: @Effie is it possible tun device add 6 byte before in write buffer

Comment: no idea, never worked with tun devices.

Comment: @Effie how come they are even inserted in first 6 bytes those zeros. any idea

Comment: `int j=(struct iphdr *)(ip->ihl*4);`, compare with `int i=iph->ihl*4;`

Comment: next, print your buff and buff1 byte by byte.

Comment: @Effie do u mean 

`for(i=0;i<length;i++){   
    if(buf[i]==buf_1[i])
    {
        printf(%x %x);

    }
}`

what this will accomplish

Comment: no, i mean "for ( i from 0 to total lengh) pritnf (%x)" for each one. we need to check if the packet is correct in bytes. i mean both packets.

Comment: do not compare them before printing. print both. `if(buf[i]==buf_1[i])` i don't need this.  they are supposed to be different.

Comment: @Effie my iph->ihl is zero

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240464/discussion-between-effie-and-user786).

Comment: @Effie yes my 6 bytes are 0. so I need to resolve this I think, But in write I tried like `write(tun_fd,buf_1+6)` still raw frames in wireshark

Comment: chat! click the link

Comment: and can i please see the bytes in both source and destination packets. unless of course IP addresses are a secret that you can't share.

Comment: @Effie I will share. I am off computer right now. Will share soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Partial Answer**

summary of the chat discussion so far.

The issue turned out to be in the opening of TUN interface, in a code, which is not shown.

Opening TUN interface is shown in [this link](https://www.gabriel.urdhr.fr/2021/05/08/tuntap/). In section "basic usage"  there is a following code snippet

```c
int fd = open("/dev/net/tun", O_RDWR);
struct ifreq ifr;
memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
ifr.ifr_flags = IFF_TUN | IFF_NO_PI;
strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, "tun0", IFNAMSIZ);
ioctl(fd, TUNSETIFF, &ifr);
```

The usage of `IFF_NO_PI` is explained in section "TUN interfaces" below. If this flag is not set, the packet (i.e., what is written in buffer in `recvlen=read(_tun_fd,buf,VPN_MAX_MTU);`) is prefixed by a `struct tun_pi` ([link](https://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/linux/kernel/3.7/structtun__pi.html)), which contains some flags and protocol. Protocol is the value that is usually written in ethertype in Ethernet header.

Since OP did not set the `IFF_NO_PI`. The IP header in variable `buf` contained 4 bytes of `struct tun_pi`, which, as can be seen from the code is ignored. Since OP is trying to parse IP header where there is no IP header, the code does not work.

Writing to the descriptor also ignored the `struct tun_pi`, which I think resulted in the kernel not interpreting the packet correctly.

#### debugging process

- there is a screenshot from wireshark. one can see that instead of an IP packet it contains some strange structure starting with several zeros and random numbers. IP header should start with bytes `45`. So the next step is to figure out what are the values in `buf` and `buf_1`.
- after getting the content of the buffers printed, it turned out that `buf` started with `00 80` and then `45 ...` (... - the rest of IP packet). Obviously, the packet in `buf` is not parsed correctly, and `buf_1` is filled with some random values from buf instead of intended values. Looking for format returned by `tun` descriptor, I have found the link above.
- currently the packet is parsed as IP header in wireshark, but `protocol` field of IP header is parsed as ICMP in wireshark.

#### issues in code

**(1)**, is that the code that parses the packet is not checking whether the code is correct.

First, after the line `recvlen=read(_tun_fd,buf,VPN_MAX_MTU);` the packet is parsed without reading the value of recvlen. somewhere later there is a `if (recvlen > 0) {` line, which actually should follow the `read` line.

Also, before casting `buf` to `iphdr` one needs to check that the buf is at least 20bypes (or `sizeof(struct iphdr)` long. Before casting next header to TCP one needs to check that the protocol is indeed TCP (by value of `iphdr->protocol`) and the buf is long enough to contain TCP header

**(2)**: `ip->tot_len     = sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct tcphdr);` unless there is no content in tcp header (not visible from the code), the length should be total length of the packet, not the length of two headers

**(3)**: the line `writelen = write(_tun_fd, buf_1, sizeof(*ip));` the last parameter should be the lenght of the packet, which is the value that should be written in `ip->tot_len`

**(4)**: some values probably need to be translated from host to network byte order.